# Forwarding instantiation of generic interface to other generic interface

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a generic interface IApiService responsible for making GET calls to other server. I have three requirements:

- some usages have to be cached
- some usages never should be cached
- some usages don't care about caching and should have default setting that can be easily changed

My idea was to introduce the following hierachy:

```
public interface IApiService<T> where T : class
{
    Task<T> GetAsync(IRequestParameters requestParameters);
}


public interface ICachedApiService<T> : IApiService<T> where T : class
{
}

public interface IDirectApiService<T> : IApiService<T> where T : class
{
}
```

For case 1 I use **ICachedApiService**, for case 2 I use **IDirectApiService** and for case 3 I use **IApiService**.

I use .NET Core default dependency injection framework. And here's my configuration for **ICachedApiService**:

```
serviceCollection.AddScoped(typeof(ICachedApiService<>), typeof(CachedApiService<>);
```

For **IDirectApiService** it's different and I have to use lambda method for each generic type

```
serviceCollection.AddScoped<IDirectApiService<ProductDTO>>(serviceProvider => new 
    DirectApiService<ProductDTO> (
        ProductsEndpoint // and other type specific data
));
```

The question is how can I configure **IApiService** to use either **IDirectApiService** or **ICachedApiService**?
For **ICachedApiService** it's easy:

```
serviceCollection.AddScoped(typeof(IApiService<>), typeof(CachedApiService<>));
```

For **IDirectApiService** I would prefer not to repeat the configuration for each concrete type as this is error prone and needs more changes if I want to switch to cached version. Is this possible with any dependency injection framework? Is there a way to somehow get the generic parameter that is missing in getService?

```
serviceCollection.AddScoped(typeof(IApiService<>), x => x.GetService<???>());
```

Comment: Point 3 sounds like it's not cached / the same as point 2, you cannot program 'not caring' into a DI framework. This sounds like you will need some kind of service factory class that creates a `DirectApiService` based on the generic type